# Partial template specialization question

Tags: c++, templates

```
class FooInterface {
  virtual void toggle() = 0;
};

template <class TYPE, class CONFIG>
class Foo : public FooInterface {
  virtual void toggle();

  TYPE value_;
};

template <>
void Foo<bool, class CONFIG>::toggle() {
  if (CONFIG::canToggle())
    value_ = !value_;
}

struct MyConfig {
  static bool canToggle() {
    return false;
  }
};

int main() {
  Foo<bool, MyConfig> foo;
}
```

That's an accurate approximation of what I'm dealing with. I basically want to have a specialized method for dealing with a *TYPE*, while keeping the *CONFIG* generic. So, for example, I might have a dozen different *Foo::toggle()* methods with specialized code handling specific *TYPEs*, but what's used from *CONFIG* will be consistent across all of those methods.

**The problem** is the previous code doesn't compile, along with several different combinations, and I'd appreciate some help finding a different solution or some workaround to make the current one work.

Edit: I should note that the previous code works without the CONFIG template parameter.

Comment: If you specialize one parameter, you should still have the other one in `template<class CONFIG>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dispatch

```
template<class CONFIG, class C>
void toggle_impl(type<bool>, C &c) {
  if (CONFIG::canToggle())
    c.value_ = !c.value_;
}

template <class TYPE, class CONFIG>
class Foo : public FooInterface {
  virtual void toggle() {
      toggle_impl<CONFIG>(type<TYPE>(), *this);
  }
  TYPE value_;
};
```

Comment: Honestly, this is the best solution. Specializing dozens of classes for various types where specialization is only needed in one method would be a nightmare. I wish I thought of this.

Answer (score 2):

You need to partially specialise the whole class. You can't specialise individual member functions.

```
template <class CONFIG>
class Foo<bool, CONFIG> : public FooInterface
{
   virtual void toggle();
   bool value_;
};  

template <class CONFIG>
inline void Foo<bool, CONFIG>::toggle()
{
   if (CONFIG::canToggle())
     value_ = !value_;
}
```